# how to handle conditional ng-class

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-class

I have a html format like this , when sec.newValue is not empty I want it to be displayed bold and if its empty , I want to display as it is. so how can I achieve this using ng-class,i tried giving fontweight : bold but it doesn't work

```
<label class="message">
<span ng-repeat="sec in error" ng-class="{secNew?!sec.newValue }">{{sec. error}}</span>
</label>
```

```css
.secNew {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: {secNew: !sec.newValue}

Comment: i am saying about , my font-weight : bold is not reflecting

Answer (score 2):

You pass an object whose key is the class to add, and the value is the condition which, when true, makes the class to actually be attached

```
{secNew: sec.newValue}
```

will apply class `secNew` only if `sec.newValue` returns something truthy.

Comment: you must need a function to return true or false because it's needing when sec.newValue is not empty